# Why is this logo in my header off-center, and how can I fix it?

Tags: html, css, joomla

Here is my site: http://mylifeiscode.com/studentprintz/

In Chrome the logo loads centered, but in Firefox and IE it's off to the right.  I've fiddled with the CSS in it for an hour, and I can't understand why it's being pushed to the right in the other two browsers.

Does anybody know what CSS property is doing this?

Comment: clearfix sucks, just to let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely positioning, but not telling where to position. Change the margins to positions. So, instead of:

```
a#logo, #logo-text { position: absolute; margin-top: 25px; margin-left: 5px; }
```

try

```
a#logo, #logo-text { position: absolute; top: 25px; left: 5px; }
```

Comment: That fixed it right up.  In retrospect that was pretty silly of me to exclude, but I think my eyes were so used to scanning over that line that I didn't see the error.  Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. Sometimes you just need an extra set of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

In the template.css on line 40, change this:

```
margin-left: 5px;
```

to this:

```
left: 5px;
```

Just as a side note, if you use Firefox, I would recommend downloading Firebug to you can mess around with the CSS in case something like this occurs.